# How to create moc files in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: visual-studio, qt, moc

Currently I am using Visual Studio 2013 on Windows 8.1.
I have installed the QT5 add-in with version QT 4.8.3(Because I couldn't install QT4 add-in). When running my project, almost moc files are generated. But my class didn't generate moc files. How am I able to generate it?

Comment: I read this link :https://truth2.wordpress.com/2010/09/04/custom-build-rules-for-qt-under-visual-studio-2010/ and follow . But don't succes

Comment: Try erasing `Q_OBJECT` in the header file, save, re insert `Q_OBJECT` and saving again.

Comment: Poor me! I have tried. But didn't sucess. Tks :)

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to resovle my problem. If a class don't generate moc file, you check again their properties. Copy another property for it.